# How can someone answer a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36622102/4121347) question. It was marked as duplicate at `2016-04-14 11:46:19Z`.

This question has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622125/4121347), which was given at `2016-04-14 11:46:54Z`.

I have experienced that when I am writing an answer, and it is closed in the meanwhile, then I am not able to answer it. So, how did he answer that?

Comment: short answer: there is no server side check for this.

Comment: @Rizier123 What do you mean? I didn't get it.

Comment: If the answer gets submitted there is no server side check if the question is already closed or not AFAIK.

Comment: If you hang around Java, you'll see a lot of that happening. Unfortunately...

Comment: You all mean to say that he _cheated_ the system?

Comment: Almost @Rizier123, there's a grace period. The check is made

Comment: @Tunaki that's because Java concurrency is rather weak?